# Read data from excel sheet using SharePoint2010 Excel Services

Tags: web-services, client-object-model

I am working with SharePoint 2010. I am created client object model application to access data from Excel Sheet which is uploaded on SharePoint Server. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this it may helps you :

http://sharepointfordeveloper.blogspot.in/2011/12/sharepoint2010-excel-services-to-read.html#!/2011/12/sharepoint2010-excel-services-to-read.html

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get information out of Excel Services from client side is to use the REST api see [Using the Excel Services 2010 REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff961897.aspx)